# Excel - How do I find 2 different values in the same column and let header appear as result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to search for 2 different values in the same column. If it is a match, I want to have the header of the 2 values in same column appear as result.

All the colored lines are standard layout and don't change.

Rows 3, 4, 8 and 9 are lines which I manually edit. The green row is the critiera. `Value A-1` means I need to find which column has `Value A` and `Value 1`.

So as you can see `Value A` can be found in multiple columns but there is only 1 in combination with 'Value 1'. These are found in 'Block 1' - 'Header 1'. This means the info 'Block 1' and 'Header 1' will appear under the green line 'Value A-1'. I'd like these 2 values (`Block 1` and `Header 1` to appear in the cells as I've sown in the diagram below). Everything under the green row needs to be automatically populated, I've just entered some values to show the expected result.

Show header if 2 values appear in same column:
[image: Show header if 2 values appear in same column]

Comment: @Izamani Can there be more than one match?  Can a pair match in both blocks?

Comment: That was going to be the next step. I want it to be unique but it is not an issue if it not. Because im afraid the info will conflict with eachother. Because as you can see I use as example 'Value 1'  several times, but also 'Value A'. The combination have to be unique but like I said it isn't a problem if it is not unique

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Im sorry to say I dont understand the ctrl + shift part. so what I did was copy your formula, paste it in the bar and did ctrl + shift + enter but its stuck at "Block part (at the first "Block 1"). it auto-select that part without the spacebar 1" part.

Comment: I have a second sheet with a list of named formula's. So all the cells with the names 'Value A' 'Value B', etc are in there. and also 'Value 1' 'Value 2' which is named to 'Value A'. Also another row (mostly same names some are different) 'Value 1' 'Value 2' etc named to 'Value B'. So what I did, I made a dropdown menu for row 3, 4, 8 and 9.

Comment: @Izamani You need to learn about array-formulas.  I suggest Excel HELP for *array-formulas*. Also [Chip Pearson's Introduction to Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx).

Comment: @Izamani  With regard to your other comments, my answer addresses the question you wrote.  I cannot possibly know how that differs from your actual data.  You will need to adapt my response to your real data.  If you run into trouble, please read the Help topic for this forum on how to provide a useful example. And also be sure to present what you have tried, and what the actual and expected outcome was.  Do this by editing the body of your question or posting a new question and **NOT** as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If there can be only a single matching pair, and assuming the layout as shown above, you can use these formulas:

```
A14:  =IF(OR((FirstValue=$A$3:$E$3)*(LastValue=$A$4:$E$4)),"Block 1", IF(OR((FirstValue=$A$8:$E$8)*(LastValue=$A$9:$E$9)),"Block 2",""))

A15:  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(((FirstValue=$A$3:$E$3)*(LastValue=$A$4:$E$4)+(FirstValue=$A$8:$E$8)*(LastValue=$A$9:$E$9))),$A$2:$E$2),"")
```

The formula in A14 is an array type formula and should be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Excel will place braces (<kbd>{...}</kbd> around the formula.

Select `A14:A15` and fill right to `E14:E15`

FirstValue and LastValue are named formulas created as follows:

With some cell in column A selected, Formula ► Define Name

```
FirstValue *Refers to*  =LEFT(Sheet2!A$13,FIND("-",Sheet2!A$13)-1)
LastValue  *Refers to*  ="Value " & MID(Sheet2!A$13,FIND("-",Sheet2!A$13)+1,99)
```

(You don't have to use Named formulas; you could substitute the above in the formulas I provided, but Named formulas seem more convenient here).

If there are duplicate matches in Block 1 and Block 2, the results will be unexpected.  But the formulas can be modified (although a VBA routine would be simpler)

`FirstValue` and `LastValue` return the individual values in row 13, reworked to be in the same format as stored in your Blocks.

Look at HELP for the `LOOKUP` function to understand how that is working.  Also use the `Evaluate` button on the `Formulas` tab to work out how the formulas are working.